# HTML/CSS: Cufón and Font-face not equal

Tags: html, css, font-face, cufon

I have a site where some special fonts are used. I'm trying to convert the current Cufón font to CSS3 font-face. Here is the font: http://uploads.dennismadsen.com/font/springsteel-lig.otf

It seems that the new Font-face is bigger and bolder when the Cufón font. I have made a test page, where I am using both Cufón and Font-face:
http://uploads.dennismadsen.com/font/

As you notice the size and weight are not equal. Why?

The Cufón has been generated here: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/. The Font-face has been generated here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator. I need the font-face to have the same weight as the Cufón which are used now. All my files can be downloaded here: http://uploads.dennismadsen.com/font/archive.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @font-face and Cufon will always look different because in both cases, those fonts are being "drawn" and it is up to the browser how well it's drawn.  @fonts tend to look more jagged.  Cufon looks cleaner but it has accessibility issues, sometimes it won't print, it can't be copied/pasted, etc.  @font solves those issues but doesn't look as good.  The differences are just something we all just have to accept: @font will never look exactly like Cufon (as much as I wish it did).

Answer (score 4):

Here are some browsers displaying @font-face differently:

[image: differences between cufon and @font-face on many browsers, mainly on XP-SP3 and also Ubuntu]